# Reopen Nomination: question about opening Terminal for programming

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, locked-posts, historical-lock

This meta post is in regards to the "historically locked" question here:

> **[Open terminal here in Mac OS finder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420456/open-terminal-here-in-mac-os-finder)**
>
> **568k** Views | **443** Bookmarks | **682** Upvotes | **900** Upvote Accepted Answer

I am proposing that this question be reopened on Stack Overflow.

---

Reading [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
, I nominate that the question generally covers:

> software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Terminal usage is not *fully* unique to software development, but substantially so. The [terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminal) tag contains [many open, similar questions regarding Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminal?tab=Votes).

The question is answerable using a variety of specific techniques, all designed to enable programmers to better use their Terminal software development tool.

The question is *practical* and useful for working programmers. Observe the 568k views on the question and 682 / 900 upvotes prior to historical closure. It's clearly a desired software development workflow improvement.

---

Moving into the next part of the list, *Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:*

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

This could *possibly* apply. But the spirit of that rule seems to be for more open-ended "recommendation" questions without a specific ask. This question is a clear, practical requirement that can be **answered**.

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

Terminal is a tool primarily (or at least *substantially*) used for programming. This is not a general-purpose macOS or server administration question; it's a question by and for programmers who are programming in Terminal and/or using Terminal as a software development tool.

---

Notes:

- The text in the question is slightly "recommend a tool", which perhaps lead to the closure. I would be happy to edit this question into a canonical question that avoids the low quality recommendation request text. (But I can't, because of the Historical Lock).
- This question would also be at home on Ask Different, Super User, etc. But the question *does* exist here on Stack Overflow, and does seem to hit the requirements for a question here about programming tools. See also the Shell Scripting question below.

  - This question gets a huge number of views and search engine hits. But it cannot be improved due to the closure and historical lock. Reopening the question would allow for an improved question edit and for better, more modern Answers.
- This similar reopen request serves as a guide: [Shell scripting question closed and locked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379912/1265393)

  - The comments and answers there are thoughtful and fully examine the benefits of opening such a programming-related question rather than leaving it locked and un-improvable yet still accumulating many views.
  - [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246215/1265393) *was* reopened, 5 years after its historical lock.

Thank you for your consideration and thoughts.

Comment: Note that the question you reference as previous case was edited to say "I am writing a shell script that takes file paths as input." which makes it more likely to fall within the "unique to software development" restrain of SO scope. That question isn't very likely to have such solution, since it doesn't ask to do something programmatically, but merely to alter the configuration of the file manager (in this case, the context menu). A example of why this question is off topic is because on AskDiferent the same question is on topic, which makes it very hard to argue that it would be so for SO.

Comment: And now that I think it better, there's nothing there that the AskDifferent question doesn't already include in their answers. If there's a better version of this question elsewhere, maybe we should just pull the plug and allow the other to rise in the search engine results.

Comment: "Terminal usage is not fully unique to software development, but substantially so" - No. Not even remotely. The terminal is used for _so much more_ than programming, and especially in the Unix and Linux world

Comment: @Braiam I'd prefer it to be reopened, but being deleted or de-indexed from Google would also be preferable to the current state, where it is the top SEO result but cannot be answered or improved.

Comment: This question has much more upvotes than downvotes. People did find it useful. Deleting it makes no sense. Improving it also doesn't make sense, because the question should never be asked here in the first place. If you want to get it deleted you need to provide some serious evidence why you think this question is harmful and needs to be taken down. You need to convince the community more than the 682 upvotes are convincing us it should stay.

Comment: @Dharman I was agreeing with the statement *"maybe we should just pull the plug and allow the other to rise in the search engine results"*. I do not know what tools exist for that beyond deletion, do you?

Answer (score 10):

This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow and it should stay that way.

It is definitely not about programming nor software algorithm. The first two clauses do not apply.

The third clause could apply since some developers use the terminal on a daily basis. Following this logic we could ask any question about any software, because it could be used in a developers workflow. Obviously, we have to draw a line somewhere. Terminal is not used primarily by developers. Anyone can use the terminal for whatever purpose. Therefore, the question is asking about a generic piece of software.

Don't forget that the fourth clause overrides the previous three rules.

> a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Usage of terminal is not unique to software development. The page says further:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

We do not accept questions about usage of Terminal, Notepad, Calculator or any other general application unless it is programming related or the tool is used primarily for programming.

The question should be closed and deleted, but as you have noticed many people found it helpful so it is allowed to stay on Stack Overflow with a historic lock.

Comment: so why you accept many question about tmux ? what is difference between tmux and modern windows terminal ?

Comment: @sorosh Do we accept them? I remember closing a few of them.

Comment: I think, we must accept them :)

Answer (score 5):

I will start by saying that yes, that question *was* useful, but doesn't continue to be useful, since the artifact found [a place were to reside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/11323). It can be safely deleted.

Now, why should it be deleted? Because it is off topic now and it usefulness has expired.

The offtopicness of the question is easy to describe: the question is asking for modifications in the file manager configuration, in such way that it behaves like Windows. Now, we are software developers, so we may develop a solution to that problem, but such solution would require to use the API of the file manager (if it was available) or modifications to the OS.

The above is presuming we don't reinterpret the question to ask "find out programmatically what is the current directory on the file manager" (which some answers do). If this question is to be preserved in any form, this should be what it may be asking and answers that don't fulfill that objective should be deleted.

In the case of the usefulness, the question became irrelevant the moment that it was asked and answered in Ask Different. I've read the top answers on the SO version and all answers on the apple.SE version and didn't find important deviations: the same programs/solutions are used in both. There would be no loss if we decided to delete this question, not even our reinterpretation of the question is lost.

Comment: Agree that deletion is definitely a better option than the current outdated and un-editable information clogging Google results. Perhaps I should have included that option in my Question here.